# select user id from a table, using results of an array in php

Tags: php

I have a table called **users(user_id, name, surname)**. In my php code a get an array with values like that:

```
<?php

$array = array();

while($e = mysql_fetch_array($favorites)){
    $like_users = $e['user'];
    $array[]=$like_users;
}

 $arstring = implode(' ',$array);
?>
```

I want to select surname and name from table users, that their user_id is equal to those numbers exists as values in $array. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. What numbers should be equal to what and where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

`$sql='select name,surname from user where user_id in(?,?.....?)'`

The number of `?` is equal to the length of the array.

Then use

```
$query=$con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($array);
```

Then fetch the returned rows.

PS:Creating prepared statements with variable number of arguments have been asked before on SO and the method is same as I have described.

Comment: if i use outside while $arstring = implode(' ',$array); I get all numbers I want...how can I change the above code you write?

Comment: do I have to write it like this : $sql='select name,surname from user where user_id in ($arstring)'

Comment: @user2491321:No No No.This is a prepared statement.If you are new to prepared statement, then Google it to learn more about it.You can also do it by directly appending the `id`s to the query but it will be prone to SQL injection and not recommended.Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

collect all user_ids from SQL Query in one Array, then compare this array with your existing array

```
<?php

  $array = array();

  while($e = mysql_fetch_array($favorites)){
    // $e['user'] equal user_id
    $array[$user_id]= $e['user'];
   }
 ?>
```

we use $array[$user_id] to save each user_id to corresponding array index, then compare two array as you want